# VBA Outlook: How to Get the Item Number of an Email?

Tags: vba, email, foreach, outlook

I'm looping thru each email in Outlook and I want to MsgBox the Item ID of Each Email

```
 For each myMail In myFolder.Items

    Msgbox 

 Next
```

The output should be like item(1) or item(2).

Comment: The **i** in `.Items(i)` are not unique so you cannot use it as **ID**. There is a unique ID called **`.EntryID`**. See Outlook's [MailItem.EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866458(v=office.14).aspx). So in your case you can try `myMail.EntryID` (it's a very long string).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866458.aspx) property which returns a String representing the unique Entry ID of the object. Here is what MSDN states for the EntryID:

> A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the EntryID property is not set for an Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved.

```
For each myMail In myFolder.Items
 Msgbox myMail.EntryID
Next
```

Note, iterating though each item in the folder may take a lot of time. If you need to find a mail item in the folder I'd recommend using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class.